# What windows permissions should be set to protect a directory while allowing it's contents to be modified?

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares

How can a shared windows directory be protected against, for example, accidental click-drag, while allowing users to modify and organize it's contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the following permissions to your shared directory: Read/Execute, Write Data/Add File, Append Data/Add Subdirectory, Delete Child, and (for files and subfolders only) Full Access.

From the command line, you would use:

```
icacls sharedfolder /grant myusers:(RX,WD,AD,DC)
icacls sharedfolder /grant myusers:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

The Read/Execute permissions allow the users to read and access the contents of the directory; Write Data/Add File allows the users to write files to the directory; Append Data/Add Subdirectory allows the users to create subdirectories; and of course the inherit-only Full Access gives the users access to the files and subdirectories within the folder.

Delete Child [allows the users to delete files and subdirectories regardless of the specific permissions on those files](https://superuser.com/questions/504123/ntfs-prevent-deny-directory-delete-in-a-otherwise-personal-folder).  Depending on your situation, you might prefer to leave this out.

By the same token, you need to make sure that the users do not have Delete Child permission to the parent of the shared directory.  If they do, they will be able to move the directory regardless of what permissions are set on it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a combination of permissions that would allow you to modify, rename and move items between sub-folders but stop you being able to click-drag. The latter is just a different interface onto the basic copy, move and delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the directory's read-only attribute, when it is dragged to a new location then it will prompt the user to confirm the move.  This won't stop the users from doing it but it will at least warn them.

Comment: But this wont allow you to Modify...

Comment: Marking the directory read-only in attributes (not permissions) does not prevent you from creating and modifying files inside it.